# Django: using multiple models in one view

Tags: python, django

I have three models linked via foreign keys (Guest, Item, Order(FK Item, FK Guest)). Now I want to write a view that shows the Guests' Details from the model and a table view listing all his Orders in status unpaid).

The first part I did like this. But how can I get the orders in?

```
@login_required
def guest_detail(request, pk):
    guest = get_object_or_404(Guest, pk=pk)
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = RegisterGuestForm(request.POST, instance=guest)
        if form.is_valid():
            guest = form.save(commit=False)
            guest.save()
            #post.published_date = timezone.now()
            return redirect('guest_detail', pk=guest.pk)
    else:
            form = RegisterGuestForm(instance=guest)
    context = {'form': form}
    return render(request, 'hotel/register_guest.html', context)
```

The Order Model looks like this:

```
class Order(models.Model):
    guest = models.ForeignKey('hotel.Guest', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    amount = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    item = models.ForeignKey('hotel.Item', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    price = models.IntegerField()
    is_paid = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['guest']

    def __str__(self):
        return "{} x {}".format(self.amount, self.item)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    guest = get_object_or_404(Guest, pk=pk)
    # The 404 will catch any bad requests
    orders = Order.objects.filter(guest = guest, is_paid=False)
    context = {'form': form}
    context['orders'] = orders
```

remember to add it to your context and you can access it in the template

Comment: that was helpful. Thank you. Could you maybe explain me the context['orders']=orders doest it simply end up meaning context['orders']=Order.objects.filter(guest = guest, is_paid=False)?

Comment: IMO It's just a slightly more readable version. It does exactly the same.

Answer (score 0):

you could get the Orders via the foreign key, by default (if not set via related_name):

`guest.order_set.objects`

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to query `Order` instance from given `Guest` check this my help you:
`orders = Order.objects.filter(guest=guest).all()`
this will retrieve list of orders that you want

Comment: then you can access every order individually in for loop as QuerySet is iterable (list like)